# Vue access 'on' and 'class' directives from directive

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I want to group multiple directives in a custom directive like the following with `model`:

```js
const model = Vue.directive('model')

Vue.directive('custom', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        // do custom directive stuff
        // modify binding for model

        if (model.bind)
            model.bind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
    },
    inserted(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        if (model.inserted)
            model.inserted(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
    },
    update(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        if (model.update)
            model.update(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
    },
    componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        if (model.componentUpdated)
            model.componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
    },
    unbind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        if (model.unbind)
            model.unbind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
    }
})
```

But unfortunately only `model` and `show` are available via `Vue.directive` and not `on` or `class`. As far as I can tell the other directives are getting patched in somehow and are inaccessible to me.

I'm in a webpack environment and would like to know if there is a way to access the other directives. Even if it's hacky.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access & modify the `class` of an element using

`el.className += ' myClass'`

If you just need to see the classes on it use the 
`el.classList`

To see all the options available on the element simply `console.log({el})`, you will get the options for `on` as well...

**Note** *The space before myClass is required. As to why, do the english yourself..*